# How to convert a signal into sound in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to make a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) program that converts a input 128-bit data using [quadrature amplitude modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation) (QAM, function [qammod](http://www.mathworks.se/help/comm/ref/qammod.html)):

```
M = 16; 
x = randint( 5000, 1, M);
y = modulate( modem.qammod(M), x);
```

But when I try to play the modulated signal using the sound(y) command, it does not allow me to do so.

I tried to make it work by doing real(y). It can be played, but data was lost. How do I make this data heard by a human while keeping its data?

I think it is possible, because in the old time people accessed the Internet over a phone line, on which the digital data can be converted to a sound signal.

Comment: By "does not lose data" I mean if the sound signal is saved in a wav file, it can be played, but it can also be demodulated back to its original data

Comment: What should have been a comment (by the OP): "This question should be merged into this question *[Low-pass filter in carrier modulation and demodulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890216/low-pass-filter-in-carrier-modulation-and-demodulation)* Thanks everyone for your concern"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only in-phase component with real(y), you can use abs(y) which gives the magnitude of in-phase and quadrature components.

But, I would assign 16 distinct frequencies to each 16 symbols and perform something similar to FM (frequency modulation).

Comment: Thank you, but after abs(y), can I still do demodulation on the result and get the original input back?

Comment: If you use abs(y), obviously you cannot recover the signal back (only with the magnitude of complex numbers). 

I suggest you to do some kind of frequency modulation, assign each symbol to a distinct frequency/tone. Then, generate a tone(frequency) for each symbol for a particular duration of time and append them. You can recover the message by this simple method. If the duration is sufficiently long, you can also differentiate the symbols with the appropriate selection of frequencies.

Also, I might write a MATLAB code within a few weeks since I have a similar project.