# Low-pass filter in carrier modulation and demodulation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I'm designing a project in which an array is passed through [quadrature amplitude modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation%27) (QAM) modulator, and then do carrier modulation, make it playable with the [sound()](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sound.html) command, then demodulate it back for QAM demodulation.

Firstly, I have used the standard way of QAM modulation:

```
M = 16;
x = randint(5000, 1, M);
y = modulate(modem.qammod(M), x);
```

Then, I wrote my own carrier modulation function:

```
function [out] = carriermodulation(x)
fs = 16000;
T = 1.0 / 4000;
fc = 8000;
Q = real(x);
I = imag(x);
t = 0:T:(size(x))*T;
C1 = zeros(size(x), 1);
C2 = zeros(size(x), 1);
for i = 1:size(x)
    C1(i) = I(i)*sin(2*pi*(fc)*t(i));
    C2(i) = Q(i)*sin(2*pi*fc*t(i) + pi/2);
end

out = C1 + C2;
```

No problem so far. But when I was done with my demodulation function, I found that the result is different from the original value (the QAM modulator output).

```
function [out] = carrierdemodulation(x)
fs = 16000;
T = 1.0 / 4000;
fc = 8000;
t = 0:T:(size(x))*T;
A1 = zeros( size(x), 1);
A2 = zeros( size(x), 1);
for i = 1:size(x)
    A1(i) = x(i)*sin( 2*pi*(fc)*t(i));
    A2(i) = x(i)*cos( 2*pi*(fc)*t(i));
end
A1 = sqrt(A1);
A2 = sqrt(A2);
out = A1 + A2;
```

I think my modulation part is right. The only problem I think I have is I don't have a [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) (LPF) for the demodulation. And I should not calculate A1 and A2 directly. How do I to add an LPF to my demodulation code such that the output is the same as the original?

Comment: As a side note, you can lose the for loops and take advantage of Matlab's vectorized syntax. This single line `A1=x.*sin(2*pi*fc*t);` will result in the same `A1` as your whole loop does.

Comment: @Dan thank you for ur advice, this is my first matlab program

Comment: np, but if you're hoping to get help on the low pass filter, you need to show some attempt at understanding what a low pass filter is and how to approach designing one. People here will help you with code, but they won't code for you. Also if your question is how to design the LPF you might want to try dsp.stackexchange rather...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a low-pass filter at the receiver after coherent demodulation, that's right. But there's also a problem with your modulation. In your example, the symbol rate `Rs` is less than the angular carrier frequency `w_c` which potentially causes overlapping of spectra at the receiver. Consequently, reconstruction of the information signal will be impossible. Additionaly, in your example `fc * T = 2`. That means that the argument of the sine function is an integer multiple of 2pi and therefore always zero.

What you need is an impulse shaper (can be implemented as a low-pass filter) at the transmitter with bandwidth `w_g >= R/2`. It should be a so-called [Nyquist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) lowpass. The carrier frequency must satisfy `w_c > w_g`.

I've written a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) script that does impulse shaping, modulation, demodulation, filtering and sampling, so that the transmitted signal can be reconstructed.

First we define the parameters, create random bits and do the mapping as you've already done. Than a very simple impulse response for impulse shaping is used, namely a rectangular impulse. In the real world we're going from digital to analog domain here, but as this is a computer model, we represent the analog signal by a discrete one with sampling frequency `f_s`. The impulse shaper is simple, because it just repeats each sample `L` times.

```
M = 16; % QAM order
fs = 16000; % Sampling frequency in Hz
Ts = 1/fs; % Sampling interval in s
fc = 1000; % Carrier frequency in Hz (must be < fs/2 and > fg)
Rs = 100; % Symbol rate
Ns = 20; % Number of symbols

x = randint(Ns, 1, M);
y = modulate(modem.qammod(M), x);

L = fs / Rs; % Oversampling factor

% Impulse shaping
y_a = reshape(repmat(y', L, 1), 1, length(y)*L);
```

Now modulation. I used a carrier frequency that satisfies the above conditions: it's higher than the signal bandwidth and can still be represented with the sampling frequency used.

```
%% Modulation
I = real(y_a);
Q = imag(y_a);
t = 0 : Ts : (length(y_a) - 1) * Ts;
C1 = I .* sin(2*pi * fc * t);
C2 = Q .* cos(2*pi * fc * t);
s = C1 + C2;
```

Demodlation is straightforward...

```
%% Demodulation
r_I = s .* sin(2*pi * fc * t);
r_Q = s .* -cos(2*pi * fc * t);
```

To remove the spectral tributaries at `2f_c` after demodulation a low-pass filter is required. I used the MATLAB [FDATool](http://www.mathworks.se/products/signal/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/signal/introfdatooldemo.html) to create the filter and part of the following code. Remember: the signal bandwidth is `Rs/2`, and the unwanted tributaries begin at `2*fc - Rs/2`. This is how `Fpass` and `Fstop` are found. (It might be useful to relax these requirements a little bit.)

```
%% Filter

% Design filter with least-squares method
N     = 50;           % Order
Fpass = Rs/2;         % Passband Frequency
Fstop = 2*fc - Rs/2;  % Stopband Frequency
Wpass = 1;            % Passband Weight
Wstop = 1;            % Stopband Weight

% Calculate the coefficients using the FIRLS function.
b  = firls(N, [0 Fpass Fstop fs/2]/(fs/2), [1 1 0 0], [Wpass Wstop]);

% Filtering
w_I = filter(b, 1, r_I);
w_Q = filter(b, 1, r_Q);
```

After filtering we still have to sample the received signal. Here it's just a downsampling. I used a phase offset of `L/2` to avoid the filter transitions.

```
%% Sampling
u_I = downsample(w_I, L, L/2);
u_Q = downsample(w_Q, L, L/2);
```

Finally, plot the constellation diagram and get a nice 16-QAM constellation:

```
plot(u_I, u_Q, '.');
```

You can find the complete code [here](http://pastebin.com/PJBb2xZN).

Your question touched a lot of topics of both [DSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing) and MATLAB programming. I could not go into much detail everywhere. If you have specific questions about 16-QAM modulation and demodulation the place to be is probably the Stack Exchange site *[Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Comment: you are my life saver, Thank you so much!!!!I wish I can grant you more reputation.. :)

Comment: About your (now deleted) comment: you were right. I accidentally interchanged `I` and `Q` in modulation and forgot the minus sign in front of the cosine in demodulation. I've corrected my anser.

Comment: I already solve this problem by myself, thank you!! Another question: what is FG variable in your code? And why does it fail if I set fs=44000, fc=11000 and rs=11000?

Comment: I used `fg` for the cutoff frequency of the baseband signal. But just in the comment. Setting `fc = rs` probably fails because of two reasons: 1) the impulse shaper used here has a large bandwidth so overlapping of baseband and unwanted tributaries may occur. 2) the filter doesn't work well when passband and stopband frequency are to close. You should choose a carrier freq that is significantly larger than the symbol rate or use another impulse shaper (look for raised cosine) and/or another receive filter.